# What is Reactive Database support?

Tags: database, reactive

We have Spring reactive programming, where Reactive databases like Mongodb, Postgresql etc are used. These databases do have respective reactive drivers.
By reactive do we mean that if we have 100 000 records, we will not load
all 100 000 records at once, whereas we will fetch data in small small batches.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

By concept of "reactive" means , it supports non-blocking, async and streaming with back-pressure (https://www.reactivemanifesto.org/).
If you apply same to above your scenario the reactive database drivers helps you pulling one Lakh records without blocking threads and in a continuous stream way by applying back pressure.

**Let me explain it more wihtout reactive and with reactive.**

Without reactive:

- The database driver blocks application threads ( IO wait) while it
  is fetching data from database
- Threads context switching happens after database driver fetches
  results inside application code so that app code processes it.
- No way to tell database from code that code cannot process more.

With reactive:

- The database driver works in non-blocking and async way, so no thread
  waiting while it is fetching data from database.
- No threads context switch. And as you have reactive application code
  it works in a same way( non blocking, async) on stream of data from
  database driver.
- Your application code can tell to database driver that how much of
  records has to be fetched in next call( back pressure).

**Note** that you can fetch small batches of 1 Lakh records from database without loading all at once, by using pagination techniques (SQL pagination) without spring reactive also. But as explained above it has other advantages.

Comment: Did this answer your question?